# 301 /product?title=jar&id=190 to homepage

Tags: .htaccess

i'm trying to redirect a page to homepage and cant seem to make it work with `.htaccess` for some reason

`/product?title=jar&id=190` to homepage

i've already tried

`Redirect 301 ^/product?title=jar&id=190 /`

and

`Redirect 301 ^/product?title=jar&id=190 /index`

and a couple other redirects but for some reason they are not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redirect` directive works on URL path only. Since your URL contains a query String `title=jar&id=190` you will need to use `RewriteRule` for this .

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^title=jar&id=190$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^product/?$ /? [L,R=301]
```